# Hibernate Data truncated for column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, exception, truncate

I'm building a hibernate based web application, I'm getting an exception when persisting a entity:

These are the entities involved:

```js
@Entity
@Table(name="part_validation")
public class PartValidation {

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "product_part_number")
 private Product product;
 
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "product_category_category_id")
 private Product category;
 
 @Column(name = "part_number")
 private String partNumber;
 
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "Id")
 private int id;

 @Column(name = "incompatible")
 @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
 private boolean incompatible;
 
 @Column(name = "required")
 @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
 private boolean required;
 
 @Column(name = "max_quantity")
 private int maxQuantity;
 
 @Column(name = "min_quantity")
 private int minQuantity;

 public Product getProduct() {
  return product;
 }

 public void setProduct(Product product) {
  this.product = product;
 }

 public Product getCategory() {
  return category;
 }

 public void setCategory(Product category) {
  this.category = category;
 }

 public String getPartNumber() {
  return partNumber;
 }

 public void setPartNumber(String partNumber) {
  this.partNumber = partNumber;
 }

 public int getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public boolean isIncompatible() {
  return incompatible;
 }

 public void setIncompatible(boolean incompatible) {
  this.incompatible = incompatible;
 }

 public boolean isRequired() {
  return required;
 }

 public void setRequired(boolean required) {
  this.required = required;
 }

 public int getMaxQuantity() {
  return maxQuantity;
 }

 public void setMaxQuantity(int maxQuantity) {
  this.maxQuantity = maxQuantity;
 }

 public int getMinQuantity() {
  return minQuantity;
 }

 public void setMinQuantity(int minQuantity) {
  this.minQuantity = minQuantity;
 }
 
}
```

```js
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT")
public class Product {

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "category_category_id")
 private Category category;
 
 @Column(name = "Price")
 private double price;
 
 public double getPrice() {
  return price;
 }

 public void setPrice(double price) {
  this.price = price;
 }

 public Category getCategory() {
  return category;
 }

 public void setCategory(Category category) {
  this.category = category;
 }

 public int getProductId() {
  return productId;
 }

 public void setProductId(int productId) {
  this.productId = productId;
 }

 public String getPartNumber() {
  return partNumber;
 }

 public void setPartNumber(String partNumber) {
  this.partNumber = partNumber;
 }

 public String getDescription() {
  return description;
 }

 public void setDescription(String description) {
  this.description = description;
 }

 public String getProductLine() {
  return ProductLine;
 }

 public void setProductLine(String productLine) {
  ProductLine = productLine;
 }

 public String getFormFactor() {
  return FormFactor;
 }

 public void setFormFactor(String formFactor) {
  FormFactor = formFactor;
 }

 public String getWarranty() {
  return warranty;
 }

 public void setWarranty(String warranty) {
  this.warranty = warranty;
 }

 public String getSoftware() {
  return software;
 }

 public void setSoftware(String software) {
  this.software = software;
 }

 public String getProcessor() {
  return processor;
 }

 public void setProcessor(String processor) {
  this.processor = processor;
 }

 public String getMemory() {
  return memory;
 }

 public void setMemory(String memory) {
  this.memory = memory;
 }

 public String getGraphics() {
  return graphics;
 }

 public void setGraphics(String graphics) {
  this.graphics = graphics;
 }

 public String getNetwork() {
  return network;
 }

 public void setNetwork(String network) {
  this.network = network;
 }

 public String getDiskStorage() {
  return diskStorage;
 }

 public void setDiskStorage(String diskStorage) {
  this.diskStorage = diskStorage;
 }

 public String getDiskStorageBackplane() {
  return diskStorageBackplane;
 }

 public void setDiskStorageBackplane(String diskStorageBackplane) {
  this.diskStorageBackplane = diskStorageBackplane;
 }

 public String getOpticalStorage() {
  return opticalStorage;
 }

 public void setOpticalStorage(String opticalStorage) {
  this.opticalStorage = opticalStorage;
 }

 public String getPowerSupply() {
  return powerSupply;
 }

 public void setPowerSupply(String powerSupply) {
  this.powerSupply = powerSupply;
 }

 public String getScreen() {
  return screen;
 }

 public void setScreen(String screen) {
  this.screen = screen;
 }

 public String getWireless() {
  return wireless;
 }

 public void setWireless(String wireless) {
  this.wireless = wireless;
 }

 public String getOtherFeatures() {
  return otherFeatures;
 }

 public void setOtherFeatures(String otherFeatures) {
  this.otherFeatures = otherFeatures;
 }

 public String getIOcontroller() {
  return IOcontroller;
 }

 public void setIOcontroller(String iOcontroller) {
  IOcontroller = iOcontroller;
 }

 public String getManageability() {
  return manageability;
 }

 public void setManageability(String manageability) {
  this.manageability = manageability;
 }

 public String getPrimaryConnectivity() {
  return primaryConnectivity;
 }

 public void setPrimaryConnectivity(String primaryConnectivity) {
  this.primaryConnectivity = primaryConnectivity;
 }

 public String getPowerOverEthernet() {
  return powerOverEthernet;
 }

 public void setPowerOverEthernet(String powerOverEthernet) {
  this.powerOverEthernet = powerOverEthernet;
 }

 public String getNetworking() {
  return networking;
 }

 public void setNetworking(String networking) {
  this.networking = networking;
 }

 public String getDiskStorageController() {
  return diskStorageController;
 }

 public void setDiskStorageController(String diskStorageController) {
  this.diskStorageController = diskStorageController;
 }

 public String getInterfaceCardSlots() {
  return interfaceCardSlots;
 }

 public void setInterfaceCardSlots(String interfaceCardSlots) {
  this.interfaceCardSlots = interfaceCardSlots;
 }

 public String getManagement() {
  return management;
 }

 public void setManagement(String management) {
  this.management = management;
 }


 @Column(name="id")
 private int productId;
 
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name="Part_Number")
 private String partNumber;

 @Column(name="Description")
 private String description;
 
 @Column(name="Product_Line")
 private String ProductLine;
 
 @Column(name="Form_Factor")
 private String FormFactor;
 
 @Column(name="Warranty")
 private String warranty;
 
 @Column(name="Software")
 private String software;
 
 @Column(name="Processor")
 private String processor;
 
 @Column(name="Memory")
 private String memory;
 
 @Column(name="Graphics")
 private String graphics;
 
 @Column(name="Network")
 private String network;
 
 @Column(name="Disk_Storage")
 private String diskStorage;
 
 @Column(name="Disk_Storage_Backplane")
 private String diskStorageBackplane;
 
 @Column(name="Optical_Storage")
 private String opticalStorage;
 
 @Column(name="Power_Supply")
 private String powerSupply;
 
 @Column(name="Screen")
 private String screen;
 
 @Column(name="Wireless")
 private String wireless;
 
 @Column(name="Other_Features")
 private String otherFeatures;
 
 @Column(name="IO_Controller")
 private String IOcontroller;
 
 @Column(name="Manageability")
 private String manageability;
 
 @Column(name="Primary_Connectivity")
 private String primaryConnectivity;
 
 @Column(name="Power_Over_Ethernet")
 private String powerOverEthernet;
 
 @Column(name="Networking")
 private String networking;
 
 @Column(name="Disk_Storage_Controller")
 private String diskStorageController;
 
 @Column(name="Interface_Card_Slots")
 private String interfaceCardSlots;
 
 @Column(name="Management")
 private String management;
 
 @Column(name="Quantity")
 private String quantity;

 public String getQuantity() {
  return quantity;
 }

 public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
  this.quantity = quantity;
 }
}
```

```js
@Entity
@Table(name="CATEGORY")
public class Category{

 
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name="category_id")
 private Integer categoryId;
 
 @Column(name="language_id")
 private char languageId;
 
 @Column(name="category_name")
 private String categoryName;
 
 @Column(name="category_date")
 private Date creationDate;
 
 @Column(name="update_Date")
 private Date updateDate;
 
 @Column(name="category_Image_Url")
 private String categoryImageUrl;
 
 @Column(name="category_Thumbnail_Url")
 private String categoryThumbnailUrl;

 @Column(name="state")
 private String state;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy="category", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 private Set<Product> product;
 
 public Integer getCategoryId() {
  return categoryId;
 }

 public void setCategoryId(Integer categoryId) {
  this.categoryId = categoryId;
 }

 public char getLanguageId() {
  return languageId;
 }

 public void setLanguageId(char languageId) {
  this.languageId = languageId;
 }

 public String getCategoryName() {
  return categoryName;
 }

 public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
  this.categoryName = categoryName;
 }

 public Date getCreationDate() {
  return creationDate;
 }

 public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
  this.creationDate = creationDate;
 }

 public Date getUpdateDate() {
  return updateDate;
 }

 public void setUpdateDate(Date updateDate) {
  this.updateDate = updateDate;
 }

 public String getCategoryImageUrl() {
  return categoryImageUrl;
 }

 public void setCategoryImageUrl(String categoryImageUrl) {
  this.categoryImageUrl = categoryImageUrl;
 }

 public String getCategoryThumbnailUrl() {
  return categoryThumbnailUrl;
 }

 public void setCategoryThumbnailUrl(String categoryThumbnailUrl) {
  this.categoryThumbnailUrl = categoryThumbnailUrl;
 }

 public String getState() {
  return state;
 }

 public void setState(String state) {
  this.state = state;
 }
 

 public Set<Product> getProduct() {
  return product;
 }

 public void setProduct(Set<Product> product) {
  this.product = product;
 }
 
 @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
 @JoinTable(name="SUBCAT_CAT",
  joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="category_id")},
  inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="subcategory_id")})
 private Set<Category> subcategory = new HashSet<Category>();

 @ManyToMany(mappedBy="subcategory")
 private Set<Category> category = new HashSet<Category>();
 


}
```

```js
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @Override
 public void addPartValidation(ArrayList<PartValidation> partValidationList){
  
  Session session = null;  
  Transaction tx = null;  
    
  try {  
  session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
  tx = session.beginTransaction();  
  //some action  
  for(PartValidation pv:partValidationList){
   session.persist(pv);

  }   
  tx.commit();  
    
  }catch (Exception ex) {  
  ex.printStackTrace();  
  tx.rollback();  
  }  

 }
```

After I try to persist PartValidation entity I'm getting this log:

```js
Hibernate: insert into part_validation (product_category_category_id, incompatible, max_quantity, min_quantity, part_number, product_part_number, required) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
 at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
 at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
 at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
 at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
 at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
 at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
 at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
 at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
 at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
 at com.epic.ecommerce.core.dao.ProductDAOImpl.addPartValidation(ProductDAOImpl.java:136)
 at com.epic.ecommerce.core.service.ProductServiceImpl.addPartValidation(ProductServiceImpl.java:43)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.addPartValidation(Unknown Source)
 at com.epic.ecommerce.controller.cms.RuleController.loadRule(RuleController.java:133)
 at com.epic.ecommerce.controller.cms.RuleController.uploadFileHandler(RuleController.java:71)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column 'product_category_category_id' at row 1
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2109)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2648)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2362)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2280)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2265)
 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
 ... 74 more
```

I believe this happens because product_category_category_id field is too big to save it in the DB, is there something wrong with the hibernate entity relation mapping? Thank you

Comment: Can you try this from an sql client such as MySql Workbench?

Comment: product_category_category_id should have the same type as product_id in the Product table